# Need help with mathematical notation in defining a line

Tags: notation, piecewise-continuity

What I'm trying to do is describe a generalized form of the following piecewise function using proper notation.

[image]

What I have so far is (excuse my non-existent latex skills):

- f(x) is defined between [0, 1]
- f(x; A, B, C) -> the function is parameterized by A, B, C (three arbitrarily named variables representing, respectively, the y-value of the flat portion of the function, the x-value at which the function takes on that sloping function, and C is the y-value at f(1.0)

```
f(x) = {
   A; if X < B
   [the linear function]; if X >= B
}
```

That is, the two components are `f(x < B) = A` and `f(x >= B) = the line containing the points f(B) = 1, f(1) = C`. The graph above is not correct because there is a discontinuity at `f(B)`, so ignore that.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the slope fixed? or do you need another parameter (say $D$) to let it vary?
(EDIT: I see, I missed the part $f(B)=1$.

Comment: Here is a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
a,&0\leq x<b\\
\frac{c-1}{1-b}(x-b)+1,&b\leq x\leq 1
\end{cases}$$

Given two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, the line passing through them is $y-y_1 = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)$; this is where the linear function for $x \in [b,1]$ comes from.

Comment: Although it is already implicit in your answer, I think it may be nice to address directly the first of OP's concerns, namely the "$f$ is defined between $0$ and $1$" part, by adding that $f$ is a function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. One follow-up question: is there a convention to choosing the variables _names_? is `a, b, c` good enough? What if I'd chosen `alpha, beta, gamma ` because I think Greek symbols look more legit?

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira You're welcome. Variable names are relatively flexible; it really depends on context. You could certainly go with $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, but there's nothing wrong with $a, b, c$. Intuitively, with $a,b,c$ in a sequence, we might expect them to have similar roles, whereas in this case they're representing a (flat) $y$-value, an $x$-value, and a final $y$-value. If you want alternatives, you could consider something like $h_0, k, h_1$ instead of $a,b,c$. That way, you have two heights, corresponding to $x=0$ and $x=1$, and the third variable, $k$ is clearly separate.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you again.